# How to iterate elements from an array and translate them using angular-translate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-translate

I have a json file that contains a few variables, including an array. In my template I use ng-repeat to iterate through this array and display each element. The number of elements in the array can change, because the json is retrieved through a web service call.

Now I want to use angular-translate to enable multiple languages. I am trying to use angular-translate-loader-url for this.

The problem is that I don't see how I can use it with ng-repeat. The values can be accessed by specifying their keys. In the usual case you know the key, and the number of keys, but that's not so in my case where it's all dynamic. I don't really care about the key names. What I need is a scope variable that holds all these keys, so that I can iterate. I don't see a way to get the data in a scope variable...

I can see that the fundamental problem is that I have the strings in an ordered array, and that doesn't seem to be supported by angular-translate. What would be a good solution?

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928431/angularjs-and-i18n-apply-ng-repeat-filters-after-translating-list-items-proper. You need to write a custom filter and pass it through your ng-repeat.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want to create a custom filter and then pass the filter through your repeater...

E.g...

```
myApp.filter('translateFilter', function($translate){
    return function(input, param){
        //Iterate through each item, translate using $translate, then return the translated items
    }
});
```

Then use you can use your filter however you wish:

```
<li ng-repeat="car in cars | translateFilter:search">
    {{ car.name | translate }}
</li>
```

etc.

Please see the following for a full example: [AngularJS and i18n : apply ng-repeat filters after translating list items properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928431/angularjs-and-i18n-apply-ng-repeat-filters-after-translating-list-items-proper)

Comment: This would mean that I need a separate ws call to get the translations, right? One for the data, one for the translations?